# Redefinition of 'function name'?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a little game that occurs in a hospital. Here's the code:

first the header:

```
#ifndef Hospital_Patient_h
#define Hospital_Patient_h

class Patient
{
public:
    Patient();
    bool cured();
    bool died();
    bool treatable();
    void treat();
    void untreated();
    char consonant();
    char vowel();
    std::string getName();


    int age;
    int health;
    std::string name;

    bool operator==(const Patient &other)const;


};
#endif
```

and here's the cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Patient.h"
using namespace std;

char CONSONANTS[] = 
{'b','c','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','m','n','p','r','s','t','v','z', '\0'};
char VOWELS[] = 
{'a','e','i','o','u', '\0'};
//generates a patient with initial health, a name, and an age from 10-79
Patient::Patient()
{
    int a= rand() % 80 + 10;
    health= 50;
    name= getName();
    age= a;
}

bool Patient::cured() {
    return health >= 100;
}

bool Patient::died() {
    return health <= 0;
}
//treatable if not dead and not cured
bool Patient::treatable() {  
    return !died() && !cured();
}

void Patient::treat() {
    if(treatable()) health= min(health + 10, 100);
}

void Patient::untreated() {
    if(treatable()) health= max(health - 1, 0);
}   

char Patient::consonant() 
{
    int index = rand() % 17; //CONSONANTS.size();
    return CONSONANTS[index];//rand.nextInt(CONSONANTS.length)];
}

char Patient::vowel() 
{
    int index = rand() % 5; //VOWELS.size();
    return VOWELS[index];//rand.nextInt(VOWELS.length)];
}

//generate a random name
string Patient::getName(){
    string s;
    s+=toupper(consonant());
    s+= vowel();
    s+=consonant();
    s+=vowel();
    if (rand() % 3 == 0) {
        s+=consonant();
    }
    if (rand() % 3 == 0) {
        s+=consonant();
        s+=vowel();
    }
    s+=(' ');
    s+=toupper(consonant());
    s+=vowel();
    if (rand() % 3 == 0) {
        s+=consonant();
    }
    s+=consonant();
    s+=vowel();
    if (rand() % 3 == 0) {
        s+=consonant();
    }
    if (rand() % 3 == 0) {
        s+=consonant();
        s+=vowel();
    }
    return s;
}
//overload ==
bool Patient::operator==(const Patient &other)const{
    //compare each room's room number field
    return (this->age == other.age && this->name == other.name);
}
```

so far after each of the functions I get an error saying Redefinition of 'function name'

I'm also having issues with the constructor and assigning values to the variables defined in the header.  The header also isn't liking std:: for some reason and I know I should never have using namespace in the header.

Comment: One problem is you need `#include <string>` in the header.

Comment: Where exactly does the error occur, what does it read, and how exactly do you invoke the compiler?

Comment: the error occurs after each function...so for example :
bool Patient::cured() {...} leads to error Redefinition of 'cured'

Comment: @IanPanz: Again, provide the **exact** error your compiler outputs.

Comment: @jogojapan, that's not strictly true. If the source file includes `<string>` before it includes `Patient.h`, as it does, everything will be fine.

Comment: @MarkRansom Oh, true. But it's nevertheless confusing...

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `#include <string>` to the very top of Patient.h. It compiled for me when I did that.

Comment: And did you reproduce the stated error before you added that `#include`? It should have made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Just a hunch, you've included `Patient.cpp` instead of `Patient.h` in one of your files.